# What is an efficient algorithm to find the most frequent sub-collection from a list of collections

Tags: c#, algorithm, collections, artificial-intelligence

Here is an accurate description of the problem: Imagine I have two tables:

- Articles (Id, ...)
- Tags (Id, ...)

There is a many to many relationship between the 2 tables called Tagging:

- Tagging (ArticleId, TagId).

Assuming the number of Articles can reach up to 20,000, and for each article there are 3-20 related Tagging.

The goal is to find **the most recurring combination of 3 Tags**,

For example if we have in table Tagging (ArticleId, TagId): (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (2,4) (2,5) (3,4) (3,5) (3,6) (4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (4,4) (4,5)

The result should be (Combination, Recurrence): ({1,2,3}, 2) ({2,4,5}, 2)

Where the first combination of Tags {1,2,3} appeared twice (in Articles 1 and 4)
And the second combination of Tags {3,4,5} appeared twice (in Articles 2 and 4)
All other combinations appeared once at most, so can be ignored in the result

We need to calculate such a result without hitting O(n^2) complexity in time and space, is this possible?
Any help is deeply appreciated...

Comment: Is the number of different Tags huge too or only the number of articles? I would say this problem is in n^2 at least in general, but can be solved kinda efficient if the number of tags is limited.

Comment: 20000 is a small number, any optimization here bears no substantial improvement. Once it increases to anything of order of 1e5, you can do the counting of tags along with iterating over the articles, storing tags in the ordered. This will yield m*log(n) run time, where is the number of tags

Answer (score 3):

> We need to calculate such a result without hitting O(n^2) complexity in time and space, is this possible?

No. This problem is NP-HARD, so, assuming P is not NP of course, there is no polynomial-time algorithm.

A sketch of why it is NP-HARD:

Suppose there are `i` articles numbered 1 through `i`.

Make a function from article to tag set `A(i)`:

```
1 -> { 1, 2, 3 }
2 -> { 3, 4, 5 }
3 -> { 4, 5, 6 }
4 -> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
...
```

Now construct a graph as follows: Nodes are either sets of tags or tags. For each set `A(i)`, if `j` is in `A(i)` then there is an edge between `A(i)` and `j`:

```
{ 1, 2, 3 } ----- 1 
{ 1, 2, 3 } ----- 2
{ 1, 2, 3 } ----- 3
{ 3, 4, 5 } ----- 3
...
```

Plainly this is a bipartite graph with a "set" subgraph and a "tag" subgraph being the two halves. Your question now is: what is the complete bipartite subgraph of this graph where the size of the "tag" subgraph is 3, and the size of the "set" subgraph is maximized?

But determining whether *any* bipartite subgraph parameterized with given sizes even *exists* is NP-COMPLETE and therefore finding an actual example is NP-HARD.